# Dismissing a screen with navigation.goBack is delayed until my heavy task finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I need to run a heavy task only after a dismiss screen animation completes.

As described in the documentation, [InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/interactionmanager) is very helpful to give some screen transition animations a priority to finish before a heavy task is started to get a very smooth user experience.

But I need the opposite,
I need a very heavy task being run only after I dismiss a specific screen.
As soon as the dismiss button is pressed, I want the closing animation finish and then my heavy task is being started.
Because I don't want to delay my closing screen transition.
Is InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions a good candidate to achieve this? And what is the proper way to handle such a situation with it?

I simply call a navigation.goBack for dismissing the screen like this:

```
...
const goBackAction = () => { navigation.goBack(null); };
headerOptions.headerLeft = () => <MyDismissButton onPress={goBackAction} />;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback parameter to onPress and dispatch an event if the current screen is sent from that specific screen you press the back button from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i don't prefer to move my screen specific logic to anywhere else. This would be my last option.